# how can I create a hidden docker container?

Tags: docker

I am looking for any option to use a flag or a filter while creating/running the docker container which would apparently hide away this container from listing out when regular `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` command is ran on the docker client

Has anyone tried it or can it be done? Please help

Comment: I don't think it can be done. If it was possible, there'd be a way to see/list these hidden containers, defeating the purpose.

Comment: I am okay to have a custom docker command to see/list this container. I just don't want it to be listed when `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` is ran

Comment: Seems like a bad idea, but you could put something like this in `/etc/bashrc` or similar for the shells on your system: `function docker ( ) { command docker "$@" | grep -v <container_id>; }`. That won't affect the current session, but the next time you log in the container should be hidden from `docker ps` (and every other `docker` command).

Comment: What's your actual end goal in doing this?  Remember that anyone who can run `docker ps` effectively has root privilege on the system anyways, and anyone who can log in can run `ps -e` on the host and see containerized processes, so there's not a whole lot to potentially gain.

Comment: Most of the time we use `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` to get container id in order to perform any action on the container - I would want to restriction any actions being performed on a particular container which is running a critical service. So, basically I want to keep this container safe by hiding away when `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` is being used unless if there is other way to restrict certain actions like stop/remove explicitly for this container @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

Only one possible solution which comes to my mind is:

1. bind docker daemon to tcp socket on port 2375 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option
2. Place reverse proxy on port 2376 which will hack communication between docker client and docker daemon by deleting hidden containers from responses
3. Set docker client to use that reverse proxy on port 2376 to communicate with daemon https://gist.github.com/kekru/4e6d49b4290a4eebc7b597c07eaf61f2#user-content-set-alias-for-linux

I'm sorry but I think it's a lot of hacking to implement that - that's why I provided only concept description.